# Roblox Studio - Why does my while loop only work once?

Tags: lua, roblox

For some reason, the while loop only works once when the script runs.

```lua
--SYMBOLS--

--! local em = Vector2.new(0, 0)
--$ local cs = Vector2.new(34, 0)
--% local ps = Vector2.new(85, 0)
--& local amp = Vector2.new(128, 0)
--' local ap = Vector2.new(170, 0)
--( local lp = Vector2.new(214, 0)
--) local rp = Vector2.new(256, 0)
--+ local pl = Vector2.new(298, 0)
--, local com = Vector2.new(341, 0)
--- local hyp = Vector2.new(384, 0)
--. local fs = Vector2.new(421, 0)
--/ local ss = Vector2.new(469, 0)

local promptstring = script.Parent.Prompt.Value
local imagesize = UDim2.new(0, 26, 0, 26)
local latin1 = "rbxassetid://12007406706"
local backgroundtransparency = 1
local texttransparency = 0
local bgcolor = Color3.fromRGB(255, 255, 255)
local textcolor = Color3.fromRGB(255, 255, 255)

--

local letternumber = 1

local function ip ()
    local letter = Instance.new("ImageLabel")
    letter.Name = "c1"
    letter.Position = UDim2.new(0, 0, 0, 37)
    letter.Size = imagesize
    letter.Image = latin1
    letter.BackgroundTransparency = backgroundtransparency
    letter.ImageTransparency = texttransparency
    letter.ImageColor3 = textcolor
    letter.ImageRectSize = Vector2.new(42, 43)
    letter.BorderSizePixel = 0
    script.LetterImage.Value = letter
    letter.Parent = script.Parent

    local extend = Instance.new("ImageLabel")
    extend.Name = "Extend"
    extend.Size = UDim2.new(0, 33, 0, 100)
    extend.Image = "rbxassetid://12049101680"
    extend.BackgroundTransparency = 1
    extend.ImageRectSize = Vector2.new(85, 256)
    extend.BorderSizePixel = 0
    extend.ImageRectOffset = Vector2.new(97, 0)
    extend.Parent = script.Parent

    letter.Parent = extend

    letternumber = letternumber + 1
    script.Event.Value = true
end

while script.Event.Value == true do
    script.Event.Value = false
    print((string.sub(promptstring, letternumber, letternumber)))
    if (string.sub(promptstring, letternumber, letternumber)) == "!" then
        ip()
        script.LetterImage.Value.ImageRectOffset = em
    elseif (string.sub(promptstring, letternumber, letternumber)) == "$" then
        ip()
        script.LetterImage.Value.ImageRectOffset = cs
    elseif (string.sub(promptstring, letternumber, letternumber)) == "%" then
        ip()
        script.LetterImage.Value.ImageRectOffset = ps
    elseif (string.sub(promptstring, letternumber, letternumber)) == "&" then
        ip()
        script.LetterImage.Value.ImageRectOffset = amp
    elseif (string.sub(promptstring, letternumber, letternumber)) == "'" then
        ip()
        script.LetterImage.Value.ImageRectOffset = ap
    elseif (string.sub(promptstring, letternumber, letternumber)) == "(" then
        ip()
        script.LetterImage.Value.ImageRectOffset = lp
    elseif (string.sub(promptstring, letternumber, letternumber)) == ")" then
        ip()
        script.LetterImage.Value.ImageRectOffset = rp
    elseif (string.sub(promptstring, letternumber, letternumber)) == "+" then
        ip()
        script.LetterImage.Value.ImageRectOffset = pl
    elseif (string.sub(promptstring, letternumber, letternumber)) == "," then
        ip()
        script.LetterImage.Value.ImageRectOffset = com
    elseif (string.sub(promptstring, letternumber, letternumber)) == "-" then
        ip()
        script.LetterImage.Value.ImageRectOffset = hyp
    elseif (string.sub(promptstring, letternumber, letternumber)) == "." then
        ip()
        script.LetterImage.Value.ImageRectOffset = fs
    elseif (string.sub(promptstring, letternumber, letternumber)) == "/" then
        ip()
        script.LetterImage.Value.ImageRectOffset = ss
    end
end
```

When script.Event.Value == true when the script is run, it works. When script.Event.Value equals true after it is run, it fails.

Answer (score 1):

A while loop executes UNTIL the condition is no longer true. It does not start looping again if the condition becomes true later.

If you want something to happen when a value changes, don't use a while loop. Consider using the [Changed signal](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/BoolValue#Changed) instead.

```lua
local letterData = {
    ["!"] = Vector2.new(0, 0),
    ["$"] = Vector2.new(34, 0),
    ["%"] = Vector2.new(85, 0),
    ["&"] = Vector2.new(128, 0),
    ["'"] = Vector2.new(170, 0),
    ["("] = Vector2.new(214, 0),
    [")"] = Vector2.new(256, 0),
    ["+"] = Vector2.new(298, 0),
    [","] = Vector2.new(341, 0),
    ["-"] = Vector2.new(384, 0),
    ["."] = Vector2.new(421, 0),
    ["/"] = Vector2.new(469, 0),
}

-- Create UI templates for special characters
local letter = Instance.new("ImageLabel")
letter.Name = "c1"
letter.Position = UDim2.new(0, 0, 0, 37)
letter.Size = UDim2.new(0, 26, 0, 26)
letter.Image = "rbxassetid://12007406706"
letter.BackgroundTransparency = 1
letter.ImageTransparency = 0
letter.ImageColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255, 255, 255)
letter.ImageRectSize = Vector2.new(42, 43)
letter.BorderSizePixel = 0

local extend = Instance.new("ImageLabel")
extend.Name = "Extend"
extend.Size = UDim2.new(0, 33, 0, 100)
extend.Image = "rbxassetid://12049101680"
extend.BackgroundTransparency = 1
extend.ImageRectSize = Vector2.new(85, 256)
extend.BorderSizePixel = 0
extend.ImageRectOffset = Vector2.new(97, 0)

local function createSpecialCharacters(promptString)
    for i = 1, #promptString, 1 do
        local nextLetter = string.sub(promptString, i, i)
        print(nextLetter)
        -- check if the next character is special
        local letterOffset = letterData[nextLetter]
        if letterOffset then
            -- create a new image of the special characters, and add it to the parent UI element
            local newExtend = extend:Clone()
            newExtend.Parent = script.Parent

            local newLetter = letter:Clone()
            newLetter.ImageRectOffset = letterOffset
            newLetter.Parent = newExtend
    
            script.LetterImage.Value = newLetter
        end
    end
end

-- listen for changes to the prompt, and generate images of the special characters
local prompt = script.Parent.Prompt
prompt.Changed:Connect(function(newPrompt)
    createSpecialCharacters(newPrompt)
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

As it stands, Your code defines a function, `ip`, then, *while* the event value is true, it will run the contents of the [While Block](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/lua/lua_while_loop.htm#:%7E:text=The%20syntax%20of%20a%20while,while%20the%20condition%20is%20true.). As soon as the condition is false, (which is immediately as you set it to false), the loop exits, and the script finishes execution.

What you're expecting to happen, is to constantly check if the Script's Event Value is true, run the code, and re-set it to false.

To make this happen, you should wrap the condition in a `while(true)` loop, and replace your original `while` with an `if`

```lua
while true do
  wait(1)
  if script.Event.Value == true then
    script.Event.Value = false
    print((string.sub(promptstring, letternumber, letternumber)))
    if (string.sub(promptstring, letternumber, letternumber)) == "!" then
        ip()
        script.LetterImage.Value.ImageRectOffset = em
    elseif (string.sub(promptstring, letternumber, letternumber)) == "$" then
        ip()
        script.LetterImage.Value.ImageRectOffset = cs
    elseif (string.sub(promptstring, letternumber, letternumber)) == "%" then
        ip()
        script.LetterImage.Value.ImageRectOffset = ps
    elseif (string.sub(promptstring, letternumber, letternumber)) == "&" then
        ip()
        script.LetterImage.Value.ImageRectOffset = amp
    elseif (string.sub(promptstring, letternumber, letternumber)) == "'" then
        ip()
        script.LetterImage.Value.ImageRectOffset = ap
    elseif (string.sub(promptstring, letternumber, letternumber)) == "(" then
        ip()
        script.LetterImage.Value.ImageRectOffset = lp
    elseif (string.sub(promptstring, letternumber, letternumber)) == ")" then
        ip()
        script.LetterImage.Value.ImageRectOffset = rp
    elseif (string.sub(promptstring, letternumber, letternumber)) == "+" then
        ip()
        script.LetterImage.Value.ImageRectOffset = pl
    elseif (string.sub(promptstring, letternumber, letternumber)) == "," then
        ip()
        script.LetterImage.Value.ImageRectOffset = com
    elseif (string.sub(promptstring, letternumber, letternumber)) == "-" then
        ip()
        script.LetterImage.Value.ImageRectOffset = hyp
    elseif (string.sub(promptstring, letternumber, letternumber)) == "." then
        ip()
        script.LetterImage.Value.ImageRectOffset = fs
    elseif (string.sub(promptstring, letternumber, letternumber)) == "/" then
        ip()
        script.LetterImage.Value.ImageRectOffset = ss
    end
  end
end
```

A `wait(1)` to pause execution after each check for just a moment, which prevents the script from taking up all the Game's Resources.